# Jquery - Find Previous 'a' class

Tags: jquery, traversal

This is probably very simple but I can't seem to put it together. I am simply trying to find the class of the anchor tab that apears right before my input field. My code looks like this:

```
  $(':input[required]').each(function () {
       if ($(this).val() === '' && $(this).attr('type') == 'File') {
           alert($(this).prev("a").attr('class')); //here is my problem it returns undefined.
           }
        }
    })
```

So i am simply trying to grab the class of the anchor tag right above my input field. $(this) being an input field. Thank you for any help.

My html looking like this:

```
<a class="ClassXYZ">File</a>
<input required type='File'>
```

Im trying to return ClassXYZ.

Comment: Your code works! https://jsfiddle.net/dqvxoguz/

Comment: its working fine it returns `ClassXYZ`

Comment: Does it return undefined for $(this).prev('a') as well?

Comment: you have an extra '}' in the code right before the ending ')'

Comment: Im still getting undefined. Does it matter that I have multiple File fields on the page? Ive cut and pasted your code and it's giving me error. Obviously your code works in the jfiddle so it must be something else on my page.

Comment: @Yatin no it says object if i just do $(this).prev('a') but when i add the .attr('class') it throws error.

Comment: If there are multiple File fields, it will just filter out the one which contains <a> as the previous element. Have you tried using .prop('class') instead? May be that will work. Give it a shot.

Comment: Using .prop is giving me the same undefined error. Hmmm.

Comment: I just realized - if there are multiple results from .prev(), then it will return the class of the first one only. Have you checked all the results from .prev() - that may be your issue.

Comment: when it loops, it alerts undefined for all file fields. Not even the first one gives accurate class.

Comment: May be you need to give an id or a name to the input you're filtering on or specify it's index and use that for the .prev() - that will give you the correct class.

Comment: This is strange. Changed class to Id (which is unique, no other anchor on the page has same id) and im still getting undefined. When i remove the .attr() it returns the object as if it's finding the element i just cant grab and attrs. IDK>

Comment: Do you have scenarios where the immediately preceding element of the input is not `<a>`? That might be the problem.

Comment: Yeah there are some elements (error warnings) between the input and the anchor. That may be my problem. I figured out a workwround alert($('form').find("a#class).attr('id'));

Comment: It should be showing you all the ones, undefined as well as the correct ones because it's running in a .each() loop. Anyways, glad you found a way.